# SettingWithCopyWarning when writing df.loc[:,'Day'] = df.index.date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datarframe with a DatetimeIndex, and want to add a column with the day to my df.
My code `df.loc[:,'Day'] = df.index.date` gives the error

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How do I do this with the index?

**EDIT**
Below is my index

```
df.index 
>> DatetimeIndex(['2022-05-23 03:00:02+02:00', '2022-05-23 03:00:13+02:00',
               '2022-05-23 03:00:23+02:00', '2022-05-23 03:00:33+02:00',
               '2022-05-23 03:00:43+02:00', '2022-05-23 03:00:53+02:00',
               '2022-05-23 03:01:03+02:00', '2022-05-23 03:01:13+02:00',
               '2022-05-23 03:01:23+02:00', '2022-05-23 03:01:33+02:00',
               ...
               '2022-05-24 21:58:29+02:00', '2022-05-24 21:58:39+02:00',
               '2022-05-24 21:58:49+02:00', '2022-05-24 21:58:59+02:00',
               '2022-05-24 21:59:09+02:00', '2022-05-24 21:59:19+02:00',
               '2022-05-24 21:59:29+02:00', '2022-05-24 21:59:39+02:00',
               '2022-05-24 21:59:49+02:00', '2022-05-24 21:59:59+02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Stockholm]', name='Timestamp', length=13758, freq=None)
```

Comment: Can you show your sample data or just index data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Hi, I did look at the example you're linking, but can't seem to get it to work without showing any warnings

Comment: @DevenRamani Added a copy of my dataframe index